# Animated color text with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

**EDITED**

I have been looking for solutions, trying to make it, but I cant do it... Is it possible to make this?

```
   <button>Button</button>
    <div id='myDivId'>
        <div class="progress"></div>
        <div class="content">
            DIV
        </div>
    </div>

$("button").click(function(){ 
      $('.progress').animate({ width: '100%' }, 10000);
});

#myDivId{background:red; color:white; padding:10px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
.content{
    z-index:9;
    position:relative;
}
.progress{
    z-index;1;
    width:0px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background:blue;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c78vF/6/)

But instead of using a background-color, change dinamically the colour of a text...

Comment: To answer your question: "Yes". To actually provide code that does exactly meet your vague requirements makes the question "too broad". Please try to implement this, then ask a new question when you come across a problem you cannot solve. Post a [Minimal Example](/help/mcve), the error you are getting that you can't solve and what you expected the code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate the text progressively changing colour, as per http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/ in your original question ...

The idea is to overlay the characters on top of each other, and reveal the top layer which is a different colour.

**SOME CSS**

```
.container { position: relative; }
.layer1 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
.layer2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
.char { color: #000; font-size: 30px; position: absolute; top: 0; }
.layer2 .char { color: #F00; overflow: hidden; width: 0; }
.char.l { left: 0; }
.char.o { left: 10%; }
.char.a { left: 20%; }
```

**SOME HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="layer1">
    <span class="char l">L</span>
    <span class="char o">O</span>
    <span class="char a">A</span>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="layer2">
    <span class="char l">L</span>
    <span class="char o">O</span>
    <span class="char a">A</span>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**SOME JQUERY**

```
$('.layer2 .char').animate({'width':'40px'}, 2000);
```

**JSFiddle Demo**

You can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zznkbsx5/). This example is simply using animate to reveal the layer, but you would replace that script with your loading logic and adjust the width of each top layer character accordingly.

Note also, that the PACE github project uses CSS transitions to do the animation, allowing them to simply set the width of the character, but this should get you started anyhow.

**UPDATED JSFiddle**

This [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattbolt/L6kw5txx/) includes center alignment and responsive width/font size adjustment using media queries.

Comment: Instead of doing it by letters, is it possible to make it by words? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: yes - the same code would apply - rather than putting a single letter in the span - put a whole word and animate the width to be wider

Comment: updated jsfiddle to show a word also ... http://jsfiddle.net/mattbolt/zznkbsx5/1/

Comment: My problem is this... I'm trying to do it in a fixed div, Who appears when page loads. When the text is completely filled with the white colour, the div fades out... But, the second title, if you apply it a X% width, it's not like yours; because of width and height. And I can't do it by px, I have to make it in a responsive way... http://jsfiddle.net/7a0o78oj/

Comment: This happens in Google Chrome when you give to the second tittle a 50% width: http://gyazo.com/d9ed6dd6a5cb5283437d552921ccd275 I really don't know why it's work in jsfiddle. It's the same code

Comment: using percentages may be causing the problem - because the element is positioned absolutely, 100% may not be exactly what you want it to be. - you could consider using the "right" property ... start at right: 100% and then set it to 0 for full width.

Comment: also - note that having "position: relative" on the parent container is important for positioning the child objects correctly.

Comment: If I put a relative position to the parent container, my div won't be the 100% of the screen size. I just want a 100% div whose text is always in the middle, and when you resize the window, the text gets little

Comment: i've updated the answer with a new JSFiddle to demonstrate these additional requirements ...

Comment: **EDITED** It worked perfectly; I had set a line height in the span tag and that displayed the layer in a bad way. Thanks too much